# Looping through url endpoints and converting json into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Please see code below:

```
rr = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(tt)):
    tes = pd.read_json(f'https://some/url/pageID={tt[i]}')
    data = rr.append(tes)
data
```

I start with an empty dataframe. I am trying to loop through a url that has many endpoints. In this case, 'tt' is a list of integers. Each integer points to an API endpoint with json. When I look at my dataframe called "data", it returns only the last row or the last endpoint in my loop. How can I fix this so I get a full dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create individual dataframe for every request and append to a list. After all requests are done, you can concat all the individual dataframes to a single dataframe.

```
df_list = []
for i in range(len(tt)):
    tes = pd.read_json(f'https://some/url/pageID={tt[i]}')
    df_list.append(tes)
final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Ah, this is correct and works for me thank you... I was so close to achieving this result on my own!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're never actually updating your 'rr' Dataframe.
If you change your new data variable to 'rr' it should work.

```
rr = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(tt)):
    tes = pd.read_json(f'https://some/url/pageID={tt[i]}')
    rr = rr.append(tes)
rr
```